# Showing most rated in PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Okay, so I got 2 tables. One holds the recipes, and the second all the ratings.

```
recipes_ratings:
id, rating, user_id, recipe_id

recipes:
id, name
```

I would like to count all the rows for each recipe. Then sort and show the recipes that are most rated and descending.

What is the simplest way to do? I have thought to make a query

```
SELECT * FROM recipes_ratings
```

And then count with a loop through the ratings, and store into array, and then sort out from that.

But can it be done simpler? One query only to do it all..or?

Comment: Perhaps something like `SELECT recipe_id, SUM(rating) FROM recipes_rating GROUP BY recipe_id ORDER BY SUM(rating) DESC;`

Comment: Actually, you might want `AVG` instead to use the average rating. You probably also want to consider filtering out recipes which were only rated once or twice since this would skew the rankings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to calculate the overall rating per recipe, you might need to adapt the calculation. But the query should be something like this:

```
SELECT r.id, product, avg(rating) as average_rating
FROM recipes r 
LEFT JOIN recipes_ratings rr 
    ON (r.id=rr.recipe_id)
GROUP BY id 
ORDER BY 3 desc;
```

Beware, that this will also output recipes without any rating. If you don't want to have them returned, change `LEFT JOIN` to `JOIN`.

Comment: This doesnt really work. It gives me some false results. I tried only having one row that gave 5 star to a recipe, and it did not even come at the top

Comment: Could you provide some test data?

Comment: I think it also goes wrong with the recipes that have been rated only once or twice

Comment: okay, got it. I mixed up the columns. The `ON` clause is now correct.

Comment: Still not right. I get some recipes that doesnt have any ratings at all at the top ?

Comment: as i wrote above: _Beware, that this will also output recipes without any rating. If you don't want to have them returned, change LEFT JOIN to JOIN._